# How to Disable Magento Review 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3.1, review, ratings

What is the best way to disable magento 2 rating & review?

I try to follow this guide https://blog.landofcoder.com/disable-magento-2-reviews-and-rating/

but can't follow the tab as it seems magento 2.3.1 has different backend structure

I'm using default luma theme

Answer (score 2):

Go to system->config->catalog->catalog->product review.
[image]

And disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command for disable the module

> php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Review

hope it helps